# Triggering a div change with jQuery Cookies on visit to a specific url

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, javascript

The following code works well, but I need it to ONLY work when a visitor lands on a specific page, let me try explain it a little better;

I have an email that goes out with an exclusive link that only certain people get and when they land on the website throught this link, I want my sticky bar to change - (the current code below changes the sticky bar based on ANY visit to any page, not just a certain one).

```
$(function() {
if(!$.cookie('repeatVisitor')) {
    // if the user is not a repeat visitor, set the cookie
    $.cookie("repeatVisitor", "true", { expires: 3 }); //expires in 3 days
}

if ($.cookie('repeatVisitor')) {
    // if the cookie exists, show the custom div
    setTimeout('showDivTwo();', 3000);
}
})

function showDivTwo() {
$('#sticky-bar').fadeOut();
$('#sticky-private').fadeIn();
}
```

As I've found out, the cookie is being set but there is nothing to trigger the code to only change through the specific URL.
One thing I have thought about is maybe binding a #(hash) to the end of the exclusive link given out

I do not want the change to be dependent on a click once on the website, I just want it to be automatic based on the visit to the specific page alone.

Can anybody help?
Again, apologies for a slight repeat of the question, although now it is a different curcumstance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the current page from the current session,

```
var sPath=window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

or something similar then take the value of SPage and compare it to whatever you need to for the validation.
You will have to have a list of codes matching to pages somewhere (in a database, on a file,etc.), or if the user is visiting that same page, store the value in the cookie so that i can be flagged as well.

There are a lot of ways to solve this issue, let me know if this helps.
Thanks

Comment: It sort of helps... I'm very grateful for the answer but I have no idea on how to implement that.  With regards to storing values in databases, this is a no go as I don't have any access to them - this is all done through a very tightly locked down cms where I can only put front end HTML in place